# Displaying and Updating Image

Tags: php, ajax, image

Basically, I have PHP code that gathers an image URL, every 5 seconds, and stores it in a string. How can I display this image, and update it using the current URL, every 5 seconds?

For example:

I have the image `http://stackoverflow.com/a.jpg` Stored in String `$image`. The image is now displayed on the webpage. 5 seconds later, `$image` is changed to `http://stackoverflow.com/b.jpg`, and now, the server displays the new value.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you are just switching between the same 2 images over and over, it can be done without Ajax just using Javascript. But it makes more sense to just make your image an animated gif.

Comment: @developerwjk It's a unique URL each time.